# Java Error when text input instead of number

Tags: java, exception, numbers, output

I am just trying to get code to work where the code asks again for an answer, if text or a symbol is entered, instead of a required integer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class timecalc {

int hrs = 0;
int min = 0;
static int hourflag = 0;
static int minflag = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public int getHours() {

    try {
        hourflag = hourflag + 1;
        if (hourflag > 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid month Please enter hours again:");
        }
        System.out.println("Enter month:");
        return hrs = sc.nextInt();

    } catch (InputMisMAtchException e) {
        System.out.println("entered invalid input " + e);
    }
}
```

Have reviewed answers already given but cant get a workable solution

Any ideas?

Comment: Get "exception" error when try run the code, works when the code is taken out:

Comment: catch(InputMisMAtchException e) {
System.out.println("entered invalid input " + e);
}

Comment: But have been trying to get this to get code to ask user to ask to inpput again to get a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't give you the entire code, but just a hint or psuedo-code. As an exercise you can implement it as per your requirement.

```
System.out.println("Enter month:");
while (true) {
    try {
        int min = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input, please enter again");
        sc.nextLine();  //  <----- advance the scanner
    }
}
```

Here the logic is to loop until we get the right input. If it is an invalid input, the loop never breaks.

*Also as a side-note, I would recommend you to create just one method to fetch correct inputs and call it respectively from other methods. Rather than duplicating this logic everywhere.*

Comment: Hi, thanks a mil for this, just I know it aint a matter of copying or pasting but working away.

Comment: Hi, Im not getting this to work. I do get the idea of a loop to work until a number is added but still cant get it applied to the code. Thanks again.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What exception are you facing? What isn't working?

Comment: {

try {monthflag = monthflag + 1 ;
if(monthflag > 1){ System.out.println("Invalid month Please enter month again:"); }
System.out.println("Enter month:");
return month =sc.nextInt();
while (true) {
    try {
        int min = sc.nextInt();
        break;
    } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input, please enter again");
        sc.nextLine();  
    }
}

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

Comment: Thats error message now. In code, have first loop to ask for correct month (>1 and <12), but second loop you suggest to loop back until answered isnt working. Thats the problem.

Comment: That is caused due to another issue. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) to solve it.

Comment: Basically its an issue while advancing the scanner obj, that link will help you resolve it.

Comment: I was just thinking, would a simple "if else" <> a number work too, just "if hrs <> 1 to 12, to ask again?

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you've tried by what you've pasted in the comments.

Comment: Was going to add an extra if statement like, if (monthflag > 1) {
    System.out.println("Invalid month Please enter month again:");
   }